# (generally) fastest way to remove set intersections

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have two sets `test` and `test1` and I need to remove elements from `test` that exist in `test1` e.g.

if `test` contains 1,2,3,4,5 and `test1` contains 3,5,6,7: then the function should be performed on `test` so only 1,2,4 are left in it.

I've discovered [set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) - is that the best way of doing things?

edit: apologies. both `test` and `test1` are `set<int>`

Comment: Usually if there's an existing standard library algorithm for it, you should use that. In this case, there's `std::set_difference`.

Comment: How do you store `test` and `test1`? Also, what container do you plan to store to the result(s) of the intersection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. I haven't tested it though.
You can use :

```
set_difference(test.begin(), test.end(),test1.begin(),test1.end(),std::inserter(test, test.end()));
```

Answer (score 0):

`set` doesn't have non-const iterator. use `list` and remove_if.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::list<int> test = {1,2,3,4,5};
  std::list<int> test1 = {3,5,6,7};

  std::list<int>::iterator ri = std::remove_if(test.begin(), test.end(), [&](int x) -> bool {
    return std::find(test1.begin(), test1.end(), x) != test1.end();
  });
  test.erase(ri, test.end());
  std::for_each(test.begin(), test.end(), [&](decltype(test)::value_type x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  });
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use `std::list` you should take advantage of [`std::list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove).